# HangFire dashboard in ABP 6.0.3 version is giving 401 error after closing the browser

Tags: hangfire, abp

I have an ABP 6.0.3 Angular UI application which is using Hang-Fire for background tasks management. I'm using Open-id-dict for authentication. I have configured the Hang-Fire as per the documentation and everything seems to be working as expected. The ABP application lets me come back to the application without having to provide username/password after I close the browser. But the Hang-Fire dashboard gives a 401 error if I navigate to the dashboard URL. When I do a proper login by providing username and password, everything seems to be working ok. Any thoughts on what's going on/how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you make the related configuration mentioned in the [HangFire documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Background-Jobs-Hangfire#dashboard-authorization)?

You should add the following code block into your module class:

```cs
app.UseAbpHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", options =>
{
    options.AsyncAuthorization = new[] { new AbpHangfireAuthorizationFilter(requiredPermissionName: "MyHangFireDashboardPermissionName") };
});
```

### Notes

- `UseAbpHangfireDashboard` should be called after the authentication and authorization middleware and before the configure endpoints middleware.
- *requiredPermissionName* parameter in the example above is optional, you can pass it as null as default.

Comment: Yes, Its all in there . The issue is only when I close the browser without clicking the logout button and come back to the application.  I think I need to do something additional so that the  "AbpHangfireAuthorizationFilter" can authenticate me .